# How to get two objects - raw Response object and POJO - all at once with Retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

I'm using Retrofit/OkHttp in a project and recently I've discovered RxJava. Combining it with Retrofit seems easy and straightforward but with regular async callbacks in Retrofit in `success(...)` we are receiving the parsed POJO and the Response. This is quite useful and in some of my callbacks I'm using both of these objects. I can't seem to find a way to do this with RxJava.

Is it possible to obtain the parsed POJO and the Response object at the same time?

Comment: I suppose you are aware of `@GET("/users/list")
Observable<Response> userList();`... so instead you want an observable that emits something like a pair of the Response AND the POJO in one ` `onNext()`. I am not aware of such a possiblity...

Comment: Yes - just like in a regular Retrofit async callback: `public void success(Object o, Response response)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way RxJava works is that the `onNext` method always emits exactly one value, so you won't be able to get something like (as it would break the contract):

```
onNext(T value, Response respone);
```

The closest could be an `Observable<ResponseAndPojo<T>>` where `ResponseAndPojo` is as follows:

```
public class ResponseAndPojo<T> {

    private final T value;
    private final Response response;

    public ResponseAndPojo(T value, Response response) {
        this.value = value;
        this.response = response;
    }

    // add getters here
}
```

Such an Observable would then emit items with:

```
onNext(ResponseAndPojo<T> responseAndPojo)
```

and you would have access to both the `Response` and the POJO.

Now, how to construct such an Observable:

One way would be to create some kind of [Subject](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/subjects/Subject.html) (maybe a [BehaviorSubject](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/subjects/BehaviorSubject.html), but for single requests it does not really matter) and then in the Retrofit `success` method put the return values into the `Subject`.

So, in some kind of `RetrofitWrapper` class of your own you would have

```
public Observable<ResponseAndPojo<YourPojoClass>> getResponseAndPojoObservable() {
    final BehaviorSubject<ResponseAndPojo<YourPojoClass>> retrofitSubject = BehaviorSubject.<ResponesAndPojo<YourPojoClass>>create();

    yourRetrofitService.getSomething(new Callback<YourPojoClass>() {

        @Override
        public void success(YourPojoClass pojo, Response response) {
            retrofitSubject.onNext(new ResponseAndPojo(pojo, response);
            retrofitSubject.onCompleted();
        }
    });

    return retrofitSubject;
}
```

As you can see, from the outside the `Subject` looks like an `Observable<ResponseAndPojo<YourPojoClass>>`, which is exactly what we wanted.